# Colour of Hot Network Questions

Tags: discussion, bug, design

I'm not sure where to post this statement, I figured here is my best chance. I find the current colour of font (#e6725a) used throughout this SE site on a white background to be hard to read on bright screens.

This isn't much of an issue for most things except when it's presented in large volumes like in the Hot Network Question section. I feel a darker (or different) colour would increase readability quite a bit.

Thoughts anyone?

Sample:

[image]

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis you removed the bug/feature request tag, which unfortunately means it won't get flagged for reading by SE staff, which I assume he's aiming to message, rather than just a passing comment.

Comment: @MarkMayo good point, didnt notice that. the tag is back now.